# Moving downloaded file to project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

So from what I understand all classes need to be within a Java project in order to run them. However, when I just downloaded a Java class it automatically opened up in Eclipse outside of a project. Because of this I also cannot simply move it, as Refactor->Move gives the error "the resource is not on a build path of a Java project". So basically because it is not in a project, I cannot move it into a project? Is there a way to overcome this without just copying the class contents into a newly created class?

Edit: also I did not have this problem until a few days ago, when I moved the Eclipse application from a random folder in which it was previously installed, to the program files folder. If anyone could shed a light on why this might have triggered it, and why this predicament was not happening before this would also be appreciated.

Comment: Did you download a .class file or a .java file? I'm assuming the latter. Just move the file using the file system explorer into the desired project/folder (shut down the IDE to avoid locks), don't try to use the IDE's refactoring capabilities.If this doesn't help, please add a screenshot of your entire workbench for us to get a better idea of what you have going on.

Comment: `Refactor > Move` is indeed used to move a class that is already in the project & update references accordingly. As @BrianFernandes suggested you have to copy your `.java` file within a Java project. You can just 1) copy (Ctrl+C) the file then 2) open the IDE, 3) select the project/package in which you want to add your class and 4) paste (Ctrl+V) or right-click > Paste.

Comment: In addition what Emmanuel Chebbi says, you can also paste Java code (text) via the system clipboard into a package and the `*.java` file will be automatically generated.

Comment: This was indeed the workaround I used, just got confused by the Refactor > Move operation not working. Thank you all for the clarifications.